# Bad Filename or Number on executing a simple Print Command in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am getting error: "Bad file name or number." at line Print(apple) on executing the below code in Visual Basic. This code gets simply called when form is loaded.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim apple As Integer
        apple = 55
        Print(apple)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please provide me the solution to the above problem.

Comment: The first argument to `Print()` is supposed to be a valid file handle/number.  Dont ignore the help that Intellisense provides as you type.

Comment: But don't waste too much time learning how to open a valid file. You shouldn't be using `Print()` in new code anyway. It's provided only for backwards compatibility with old VB 6 code. Start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y32kbeb6.aspx) to learn how to do file I/O in VB.NET the correct way.